# Natural ways to express "different levels of my address"

Tags: sentence-construction

> I live in the village of **X** which falls under the district of **Y** and that lies in the **Z** state of the country **ABC.**

Being a learner I am rather confused as to how to express this naturally.

What are the **natural ways** to express this?

Comment: What is the native language of ABC? This sort of thing varies with language, and with country, even given the same language.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty Bengali

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty How would you say it in your country?

Comment: I live at 1234 Bruce Drive, Imperial, Missouri, USA. I live in the township of Imperial in the state of Missouri in the United States of America. How is your mail addressed, @user100323?

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty in mail we write the same way as you.

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty but in spoken English can I use "fall under"?

Comment: I  would use "is in", unless it's a case where it's not physically within, but still falls under that jurisdiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably two contexts.  Firstly when you are giving your postal address,

> Can I have your address please

> Yes, it's four Privet Drive, Little Whinging, Surrey, England.

You would probably also include a zip or postcode.

Note this is country dependent, not language.  It is whatever the person should write on the envelope to get to your address.  In English, but in Japan you would write

> Japan, Saitama prefecture, Niiza city, Nobitome, 6 chome 5-55

Because in Japan the larger districts come first.

If you are writing, you would give your address like this.  You don't need any "fall under"

The other alternative is when you are telling someone where you live in speech.  Here it depends on how well the other person knows the country.  Perhaps you are meeting at an international conference.  There are people from many different countries

> Where do you live?
>
> I live in Missouri in the USA.

Since the person doesn't know about what cities are in Missouri giving any more detail is pointless.  But if you were meeting someone who also lived in Missouri, you would answer differently:

> Where do you live?
>
> I live in Imperial.

There's no need to say "which falls in Missouri"  since that's obvious.

Sometimes a dialogue can develop,

> Where do you live?
>
> In Missouri in the USA,
>
> Oh really, whereabouts in Missouri
>
> A small city, called Imperial, South of St Louis.
>
> No way, my cousin lives in Kimmswick! I often visit him.
>
> Next time, you should come round.  My address is 1234 Bruce Drive.

The situation that you describe, of giving full details of your address in on go in speech and in a flowing sentence does not occur. However expressions like "which falls in" or "lies in" are correct and could be used in an essay-like context:

> I live in the village of Hatibandha, which lies in the Mymensingh Division, in the North of Bangladesh...